# Using sed -e to replace slash

Tags: sed

I am trying to understand what this below command does with -e in sed and exclamatory marks in the command,

```
sed -e "s!VPC_CIDR!"$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)"!g" "templates/network-policies-${ns}.yaml"
```

This command helped to replace VPC_CIDR with 1.2.3.4\16.

Could someone through light on this please?

Comment: `-e` means the next item is the sed command, and `!` are used as regex delimiters here.

Comment: It worked for me with backslash in the VPC_CIDR. Just with sed 's\VPC_CIDR\"$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)"\g" , the backslash in the cidr errored out

Comment: `sed cmd file` is identical to `sed -e cmd file`. `-e` is needed when multiple command are given so that you can do `sed -e cmd -e cmd -e cmd path`.  It is often omitted when only one command is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-e` option just tells `sed` that the next argument is the script to execute. `"s!VPC_CIDR!"$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)"!g"` is the script.

The `"` usage is strange. I would just `"s!VPC_CIDR!$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)!g"`. Because `$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)` is not within `"` quotes, the result will undergo *word splitting* and *filename expansion*. Ie. it will fail on spaces and `*` or `?` characters may work strangely.

The `"s!VPC_CIDR!"$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)"!g"` is a `sed` script. The `s` command does, from [man 1 sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

> ```
> s/regexp/replacement/
> ```
>
> Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.  The replacement may con‐
> tain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to
> the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

But you think - och `!` is not `/`! But, as `man 1 sed` tells us `This is just a brief synopsis of sed commands to serve as a reminder to those who already know sed`. The [POSIX sed or man 7 sed page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) will shed some more light:

> ```
>  [2addr]s/BRE/replacement/flags
> ```
>
> Substitute the replacement string for instances of the BRE in the pattern space. **Any character other** than <backslash> or <newline> can be used instead of a  to delimit the BRE and the replacement. Within the BRE and the replacement, the BRE delimiter itself can be used as a literal character if it is preceded by a <backslash>.

*Any character*. You can evey pass *byte* 0x01, like `sed $'s\x01BRE\x01replacement\x01'` and it's a valid script.

So `s!VPC_CIDR!$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)!g` command replaces *every occurence* (ie. the `g` global flag) of the `VPC_CIDR` string (the string is literal, there are no special regex expressions there) for the output of `$(get_cluster_vpc_cidr)` (except that `&` and `\1` and such are interpreted specially in *replacement* part).